# Access list data through SharePoint Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm building a custom web part in SharePoint 2007.  It needs to access specific list item data and then format and style the output.

I'm developing the web part in C#, and would like the solution to be self-contained.  How do I access list data from this web part?  Can I use a SOAP request and process it in C#?  Should I be pulling list data through a web service (such as getlistitems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building a SharePoint Web Part, you should access the list and its data via the [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) class.

The linked document provides a short example of how to properly get a list from the current SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

Use the object model like this:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists(LISTNAME);
SPQuery query = new SPQuery() { Query = "<Where>...</Where>", ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" };
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Then just use the SPListItemCollection.  You will need to replace the Query text with a CAML query (leave off the `<Query>` element).  A good way to generate the CAML needed is to use a free tool like this one:

http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx